# How to use signature pad library with jetpack compose using Android and Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I was using this library to get signature https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad with Android app written in Kotlin, now I moved to jetpack compose and I want to use it with the new UI library

my old code was:

- XML

```
    <com.github.gcacace.signaturepad.views.SignaturePad
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/signature_pad"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:penColor="@android:color/black"
     />
```

- Fragment

```
class SignatureFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var signatureBinding: FragmentSignatureBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        setupSignatureBinding(inflater, container)

        handleSignatureClicks()

        return signatureBinding.root
    }

    private fun setupSignatureBinding(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?) {
        signatureBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_signature,
            container,
            false
        )
    }

    private fun handleSignatureClicks() {

        signatureBinding.signaturePad.setOnSignedListener(object : SignaturePad.OnSignedListener {

            override fun onStartSigning() {}

            override fun onSigned() {
                signatureBinding.saveButton.isEnabled = true
                signatureBinding.clearButton.isEnabled = true
            }

            override fun onClear() {
                signatureBinding.saveButton.isEnabled = false
                signatureBinding.clearButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        })

        signatureBinding.clearButton.setOnClickListener{ signatureBinding.signaturePad.clear() }

        signatureBinding.saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            val signatureBitmap: Bitmap = signatureBinding.signaturePad.signatureBitmap
        }
    }

  
}
```

- I was thinking about solving this problem and I found that I could go from the compose screen to activity with intent, and I did that at the code below, but the problem is I can't back to the form to complete the rest of the questions but instead when clicking on the back button it goes to the main activity of the app

```
@Composable
fun SignatureQuestion(question: QuestionModel, formViewModel: FormViewModel) {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    CustomInputFieldContainer(
        isRequired = question.is_required,
        label = question.question_title
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                val intent = Intent(context, SignatureActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("question", question)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            },
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentSize(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                    .padding(vertical = 10.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Edit, contentDescription = null)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                Text(text = "Add Signature")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on a updated version of this library since the original author don't seems to have no time to do it. Find updated version with Jetpack Compose support here: https://github.com/warting/android-signaturepad

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access xml layout then follow below code as i did with your mentioned library:

1st create xml layout with your library tag.
and then write below lines in your @composable function:

```
  val parser: XmlPullParser = context.resources.getLayout(R.layout.test_layout)
        try {
            parser.next()
            parser.nextTag()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val attr: AttributeSet = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser)
val signature= remember {
    SignaturePad(context,attr).apply {
        id=R.id.signature_pad
    }
}
        AndroidView({signature}) { signaturepad->

// here you can play with signature pad 

           
        }
```

Comment: Did you test that yourself? I tried your code but nothing showed on the screen

Comment: yes i test the code before posting it and i was able to draw on screen too. can you share your code so that i can check it ?

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I used the AndroidView and worked fine, and here is my code if anyone wanted to do it

```
AndroidView(
                    factory = { context ->
                        SignaturePad(context, null)
                    }, update { signaturePad -> // call methods here }
```